# ggplot2 error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. I have no idea

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, kaggle

I am taking an online R class in Udemy, here is the code for a Linear regression visualization. I got the error message from the last command. The data from the website about bikesharing: https://www.kaggle.com/c/bike-sharing-demand/data

The data looks like:
[image]

```
bike <- read.csv("train.csv")
library(ggplot2)
bike$datetime <- as.POSIXct(bike$datetime)
pl <- ggplot(bike, aes(datetime, count)) + geom_point(aes(color = temp),alpha = 0.5)
pl
print(pl)
pl + scale_color_continuous(low='#55D8CE',high='#FF6E2E') +theme_bw()
cor(bike[,c('temp','count')])
ggplot(bike,aes(factor(season),count)) + geom_boxplot(aes(color=factor(season))) +theme_bw()
bike$hour <- sapply(bike$datetime,function(x){format(x,"%H")})
library(dplyr)
pl <- ggplot(filter(bike,workingday==1),aes(hour,count)) 
pl <- pl + geom_point()
pl
pl <- pl + scale_color_gradientn(colours = c('dark blue','blue','light blue','light green','yellow','orange','red'))
```

the pl looks like:
[image]
I got the error message from the last command when I was trying to add colors:
**Error in if (!alpha || all(lab_in[, 4] == 1)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

I have no idea how to solve the problem, anyone can help? thank you so much.

Comment: There is a typo : you have `scale_color_gradientn` instead of `scale_color_gradient` but I think that doesn't solve either. Do you need `ggplot(filter(bike,workingday==1),aes(hour,count, color = factor(hour))) + geom_point()` ?

Comment: Thank you. yeah, I need that.

Comment: I just followed the class code. No idea about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add different colors for different hours you can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(filter(bike,workingday==1),aes(hour,count, color = hour)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But How to add colors I want instead of the default colors?

Comment: @sooo You can add another line with `+ scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink", ..... ))` 24 colors for 24 hours.

Comment: Why don't you use geom_bar() for this kind of visualization in place of geom_point()

Comment: @myamulla_ciencia yes, it can be used as well. But I was just following what OP was trying.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error here. Changing the colour word with a space to hex code solved it for me, e.g. I used `scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c("#000066","blue","#b0cceb","#6dcf72","yellow","orange","red"))`